# Rails: ckeditor gem not working in production mode with nginx and passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ckeditor

I am using the [ckeditor WYSIWYG text editor](https://rubygems.org/gems/ckeditor) in my rails project.  In particular: I am having trouble configuring for image uploads in production mode.

It works fantastic in development mode, and even locally in production mode while using Puma.  When I click to Upload a photo and click the `Browse Server` button.  It immediately looks for photos where I expect them to: within `/assets/ckeditor_assets/pictures`.

The issue is getting it to work in production mode with nginx. When I use nginx in production mode: it returns a `404 Not Found` error message.  I looked at my server logs and here is what it says:

> "/var/www/MYAPP/ckeditor/pictures" failed (2: No such file or directory)

So for some reason it is attempting to find a `ckeditor` directory within my public directory (because that is a symlink to my public directory).  I am not even sure why ckeditor is looking for a `ckeditor` directory when it should instead be looking within my apps `public/assets/ckeditor_assets` directory.

I attempted to fix this by creating a `ckeditor` directory within my public directory, and then putting a `pictures` directory inside of there.  However, when I did that I got a `403 Forbidden` error.

I did notice that within the `config/initializers/ckeditor.rb` file there is this line:

```
# Customize ckeditor assets path
# By default: nil
#config.asset_path = "http://www.example.com/assets/ckeditor/"
```

So just to give it a shot I hardcoded where I wanted ckeditor to go and fetch the pictures, but unfortunately that didn't work either.

Any suggestions please let me know.  Thanks!  I will go ahead and show my `ckeditor::picture` model file in case that provides any clues:

```
class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset
  has_attached_file :data,
    :url  => "/assets/ckeditor_assets/pictures/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/ckeditor_assets/pictures/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
    :styles => { :content => '800>', :thumb => '118x100#' }

  validates_attachment_presence :data
  validates_attachment_size :data, :less_than => 2.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :data, :content_type => /\Aimage/

  def url_content
    url(:content)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A buddy of mine figured it out. It turns out it was simply a configuration required in the `nginx.conf` file.  I'm using nginx and passenger.

ck_editor sends a request  to `ckeditor/pictures` as opposed to `MYAPP/ckeditor/pictures`.  Basically: it ignores the relative path (via passenger) of your app.  I just updated the location block regex like so:

```
# nginx.conf
...
location ~ ^/(RELATIVE_PATH_FOR_APP|ckeditor/pictures)(/.*|$) {
  ...
}
```

An alternative is that one might be able to forgo the regex for `ckeditor/pictures` within the location block by overriding some of the configurations found in [the ckeditor config.js file](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js). That way you are specifying the ck_editor routing at the application level as opposed to the server level.